# Relative layout weight

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I need to find a replacement for a Linear layout weight parameter in the case of `RelativeLayout`.

Below is the code for `LinearLayout`

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams fp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,0);
fp.weight = 2;
FrameLayout parent_frame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame_container);
parent_frame.setLayoutParams(fp);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams tp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,0);
tp.weight = 1;
FrameLayout popup_layout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.popup_layout_id);
popup_layout.setLayoutParams(tp);
```

I need to do the same if the parent layout changed to `RelativeLayout`,
I have the code below but the output is black screen.

```
   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams fp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,0);
    //fp.weight = 2;

    FrameLayout parent_frame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame_container);
    parent_frame.setLayoutParams(fp);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams tp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,0);
    //tp.weight = 1;

    FrameLayout popup_layout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.popup_layout_id);
    popup_layout.setLayoutParams(tp);
```

Basically what I need is display two layout vertically with **70%** of the screen with first layout and **30%** with second one, and I cannot use `LinearLayout` in the  xml as it requires lot of code changes.

Comment: Why don't you surround your relative layout inside a linear layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new PercentRelativeLayout is your friend:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html

Comment: I have mentioned in the question that I need do this with RelativeLayout  only, as I cannot change my xml file.

Comment: This was not clear from the question to me - why cant you change the xml layout?